# Unbound Local error in Python I can't shake!

Tags: python, debugging, local

http://pastie.org/1966237

I keep getting an unbound local error. I don't understand why it occurs, if the program is running right, it should go straight into the second assignment of the print_et_list function within the main function, looping itself without actually looping. The program only quits using sys.exit() in the hey_user function.

I included the whole program for context, it isn't too long. Let me know if you want to have  a look at the text files I use in the program, however I'm sure it's unlikely that it is the source of the problem.

Comment: You should actually put the program into the question, as pasties sometimes go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UnboundLocalError happens when you read the value of a local variable before you set it.  Why is score a local variable rather than a global variable?  Because you set it in the function. Consider these two functions:

```
def foo():
    print a
```

vs

```
def bar():
    a = 1
    print a
```

In foo(), a is global, because it is not set inside the function.  In bar(), a is local.  Now consider this code:

```
def baz():
    print a
    a = 1
```

Here, a is set within the function, so it's local.  But it hasn't been set at the time of the print statement, so you get the UnboundLocalError.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass `score` into `hey_user()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's probably the score variable.  It's a local in main(), but you try to reference it in hey_user().

Comment: Question: When I initialize score in the beginning of the entire thing, the same error still arises.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make score a global variable, be sure to declare it with the `global` statement:

def main ():
        global score
        score = 0
        question, solution = print_et_list()
        scoresofar = hey_user (solution)
        print "\nYour score is now", scoresofar
        question, solution = print_et_list()